# Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested

Tags: laravel

When I tried to create a new laravel project from scratch the following error occurred. What could be the reason and will it have any impact on the project? I am using Laravel 7

Answer (score 9):

Citing Sebastian Bergmann

> `phpunit/php-token-stream` has been abandoned. PHPUnit 8.5, which still receives bug fixes until February, uses phpunit/php-token-stream. Just ignore this message from Composer.

You have to update to PHPUnit 9 to get rid of the warning.

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20200917163338/https://github.com/laravel/ui/issues/134

Answer (score 6):

I have changed this package in `composer.json` and it worked just fine :

```
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0"
```

this is compatible with laravel ^7.4